# How to login browser based user in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I designed login page by using simple asp textboxes and button.
so now i can login on the browser and restrict if user not logged in.
so issue is if i copy the home page link and paste it another browser then its going to that page where as have to go to login page so how to prevent this
Actually I want a requirement, if user logged in one browser then login and same user trying to logging in another browser then login the application and should logout previous browser's application.
below is my code

```
public void empLogin()
        {
            try
            {
                //open the db connection if it is closed...  
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                string userName = txtUName.Text;
                string password = txtPwd.Text;
                command = new SqlCommand();
                command.CommandText = "sp_Emplogin";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter outRegistrationId = command.Parameters.Add("@CompRegId", SqlDbType.Int);
                outRegistrationId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                outRegistrationId.Size = 7;
                SqlParameter outUserType = command.Parameters.Add("@userType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                outUserType.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                outUserType.Size = 7;
                SqlParameter outversions = command.Parameters.Add("@versions", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                outversions.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                outversions.Size = 10;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                command.Connection = connection;
                int usercount = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();// for taking single value
                Session["userName"] = userName;
                Session["RegistrationId"] = (command.Parameters["@CompRegId"].Value).ToString();
                //lblLoginMessage.Text = (command.Parameters["@CompRegId"].Value).ToString(); //Convert.ToString(Session["RegistrationId"]);
                string userType = (command.Parameters["@userType"].Value).ToString();
                string versions = (command.Parameters["@versions"].Value).ToString();
                if (usercount == 1)  // comparing users from table 
                {
                    if (chkRemember.Checked == true)
                    {
                        Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = txtUName.Text;

                        Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

                        Response.Cookies["password"].Value = txtPwd.Text;

                        Response.Cookies["password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                        Response.Cookies["password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    }
                    StudentInfo _objStudentInfo = new StudentInfo(txtUName.Text, txtPwd.Text);
                    Session["objStudentInfo"] = _objStudentInfo;                   

                    string sKey = txtUName.Text + txtPwd.Text;
                    string UKey = txtUName.Text + txtPwd.Text;
                    string UOneKey = txtUName.Text + txtPwd.Text;
                    string AdminUser = Convert.ToString(Cache["sKey"]);
                    string User = Convert.ToString(Cache["UKey"]);
                    string UserOne = Convert.ToString(Cache["UOneKey"]);
                    if (AdminUser == null || AdminUser == String.Empty)
                    {
                        if (userType == "Admin")
                        {
                            TimeSpan SessTimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout, 0, 0);
                            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("sKey", sKey, null, DateTime.MaxValue, SessTimeOut,
                            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
                            if (versions == "Version2")                            {
Response.Redirect("~/AdminWithVersionTwo/AdminDashBoardVTwo.aspx");
                            }
                            else if (versions == "Version3")
                            {

                            }
                            else if (versions == "Version1")
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("~/Admin/DashBoard.aspx");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (User == null || User == String.Empty)
                    {
                        if (userType == "User")
                        {
                            TimeSpan SessTimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout, 0, 0);
                            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("UKey", UKey, null, DateTime.MaxValue, SessTimeOut,
                            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
                            if (versions == "Version2")
                            {                                Response.Redirect("~/UserVTwo/userDashBoardVTwo.aspx");
                            }
                            else if (versions == "Version3")
                            {

                            }
                            else if (versions == "Version1")
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("~/User/UserDashBoard.aspx");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (UserOne == null || UserOne == String.Empty)
                    {
                        if (userType == "User1")
                        {
                            TimeSpan SessTimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout, 0, 0);
                            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("UOneKey", UOneKey, null, DateTime.MaxValue, SessTimeOut,
                            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
                            if (versions == "Version2")
                            {                                Response.Redirect("~/User1VTwo/DashBoardUser1VTwo.aspx");
                            }
                            else if (versions == "Version3")
                            {

                            }
                            else if (versions == "Version1")
                            {                                Response.Redirect("~/User1/User1DashBoard.aspx");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('This User Alredy logged in');", true);
                        //lblDisplay.Text = "<Marquee><h1><font color=red>Already Logged IN</font></h1></marquee>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblLoginMessage.Text = "Invalid User Details";  //for invalid login
                    lblLoginMessage.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Exception Message: " + ex.Message.Replace("'", "").Replace("\"", "") + "');", true);
            }  
                    finally //Close db Connection if it is open....  
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();
                command.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: i'm confused, is your question how to make user logged in from any browser once he is logged once ? - or you want to force user to logout if he  logged in from a different browser ?

Comment: @ Mohamed Badr if user logged in chrome then login first time then again logging in diff system or browser then login and have to logout before logged app if refresh or go to another page.

Comment: Have you enabled Forms authentication from web.config?

Comment: <forms defaultUrl="~/login.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="20" ></forms><!--slidingExpiration="true"-->
    </authentication>    
      <sessionState timeout="20" mode="InProc" />

Comment: I guess this should be there -
`<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="logon.aspx" 
   protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
   <deny users ="?" />
   <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>`

Comment: i did not use asp login control..so what use of this?

Comment: and to which users denying and allowing?database users?